# Does Gödel sentence depend on numbering?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

If we change Gödel's numbering definition of the $Prov$ predicate will change as well, but the meaning won't. How is that going to affect $G$? It seems to me like it will change as it is actually $\neg Prov([G])$ and $Prov$ is totally different. Also is it possible to make a numbering, such that $G$ is $Con(F)$ or any other sentence independent of the system $F$?

Comment: Please clarify all of your notation, including $Prov$, $G$, $[G]$, $F$.

Comment: $[x]$ - Gödel's number of a formula x, F - name of some formal system, $Prov([x])$ - There is a proof of a formula x in F, G - Gödel sentence of F, $Con(F)$ is $\neg Prov([1= 0])$.

Comment: You are right; the "specific" $G$ depends on $F$ and on the coding mechanism used. But, for every coding schema, you cn find the corresponding $G$, provided that theory $F$ satisfies the condition of G's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; the "specific" sentence $G$ depends on the theory $F$ **and** on the coding mechanism used: see [Gödel Numbering](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/sup1.html).

But, for every coding mechanism, we can find the corresponding sentence $G$, provided that the theory $F$ satisfies the condition of Gödel's Theorem.